# Docker container builds locally but not on GitLab

Tags: reactjs, ruby, docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

The dockerfile builds locally but the GitLab pipeline fails, saying:

```
Step 3/8 : RUN gem install bundler rake
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/bundle directory.
```

The project strucutre is a Ruby Sinatra backend and a React frontend.

The Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM ruby:3.0-alpine

# Install Dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base mysql-dev rrdtool
RUN gem install bundler rake

# Copy the files and build
WORKDIR /usr/server
COPY . .
RUN bundler install

# Run bundler
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma"]
```

I thought Docker was meant to solve the problem of "it runs on my machine"...

### What I've tried

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893889/how-do-i-fix-the-you-dont-have-write-permissions-into-the-usr-bin-directory), I tried adding `-n /usr/local/bundle` but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: did you try specify path for bundler command?
`RUN bundler install --path vendor/`  

also there is https://stackoverflow.com/a/68258603/5347939 some options given, maybe you can try them also